# Simultaneous commit in two Branches after performing merge

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, commit

I'm using Bitbucket to store my code. The steps that I follow to deploy the changes to the development branch are the following:

1. git status
2. git commit -am "New commit"
3. git push origin to the branch I created from master

In Bitbucket, I compare the branches. If everything is OK, I proceed with the merge.

**The problem:**

After merge, in "Commits" section, I see this:

[Commit in two branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPqGe.png)

Instead of a single commit, I can see two commits: one in the branch I just created and one in the branch that I merged to.

So my questions are:

- ¿How this could happen?
- ¿Is this a serious problem?
- ¿How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help, it´s really important.

Regards.

Comment: That screenshot, is that telling you that your original commit is now in two branches?

Comment: And can you describe these two commits? Is it the same commit appearing twice or is it your original commit + a merge commit? Please be more explicit when describing your situation.

Comment: I will try to explain, excuse my rustic way to make my point.  When I push the changes to my branch, I can see the commit correctly in my branch when I check the "Commits" section. But, after merge, when I check the "Commits" section again, I can see the situation described in the image.

Comment: If that image means that after the merge, you have 1 commit appearing in 2 branches, then that is normal, a commit in git is said to be "on a branch" if you can backtrack from the commit the branch is pointing to back to the commit you're asking about. Due to merges and branch topology, every commit can appear on any number of branches.

Comment: Is there any way you can link to the commit or branch or whatnot that has that image, or find a similar situation on bitbucket so that we can see exactly what that screenshot means?

Comment: Thanks, I now understand how a git repository works. I was concerned that, because the "duplicated" commits, I could undo changes previously made by other members. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens based on the type of merge you perform. I was able to create a Bitbucket repository and merge using `fast-forward` and it generated the same "2 branches" tag next to the commit.

- **Merge commit**—Keeps all commits from your source branch and makes them
  part of the destination branch. This option is the same as entering git merge --no-ff in the command line.
- **Squash**—Combines your commits when you merge the source branch into the destination branch. This option is the same as entering git merge --squash in the command line.
- **Fast forward**—Moves commits from the source branch to the
  destination branch (if the destination has no new commits).

There's nothing wrong with how you did this. It's just one of several strategies you can use to move code changes around between branches in your repository. The link I provided goes into more detail about the various strategies and when you would use them.

If you want to undo the merge, Bitbucket has introduced a feature to do this via their website.

1. From the pull request, click the Revert button in the top right.
2. (Optional) From the Revert pull request dialog, change the Branch name for the new branch you're about to create. Click the Revert button.
3. Once you click Revert, Bitbucket creates the new branch. Even if you cancel the pull request, the revert branch remains in the repository.
4. The Create a pull request page opens with the revert branch as the source. After you add your reviewers and make additional changes, click Create.

The content of this answer is sourced from the Bitbucket documentation: [Use a Git branch to merge a file](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/merge-a-pull-request-945541513.html):

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that, even if the pipeline fails, I can see the  changes applied in the destination branch. By the way, in this merge I used "Merge-commit" strategy.

Comment: Can you update your question with some more details about your pipeline and how that fits into your need to have your fit history recorded differently?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I had a confusion between merge to a branch and deploy. I believed that, if pipelines succeeds, then merge is performed. I was clearly and completely wrong. Thanks for your answers and comments.